Can I repair this sliding window to make it close flush?
Recently bought this 1982 apartment. The walls are reasonably insulated but this window is giving me grief. I believe it is the original aluminium window and simply will not close flush leaving an air gap at the top right. I bought the thickest window seal foam from the local hardware store I could find but it is not deep enough. I also took the glass panel off to inspect but couldn't see anything to fix. Is this repairable or does it need replacement? Apologies for picture quality as my iPhone cameras appear to have fogged up as of yesterday.




in the sliding channel, there is a spring that pushes the window and keeps it in place, find that spring
